# Limit of $\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\sin(x)|^{n} \ dx$

Tags: real-analysis

How does one show that as $n\to \infty,$ $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\sin(x)|^{n} \ \to 0?$$ 
Also what about the integral $\int_{0}^{2n\pi} |\sin(x)|^{n} \ dx$ ? I am not able to proceed. I tried using the fact that $|\sin(x)| < |x|$ but that really doesn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $|\sin(x)|^n \le 1$ and we have $\sin(x)^n \to 0$ for almost every $x\in(0,2\pi)$ as $n\to\infty$ this follows from [Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

*Edit*:

Alternatively, without the use of the dominated convergence theorem, note from the graph of $\sin(x)$ that

$$\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin(x)|^n dx = 4 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)^n dx$$

Notice that $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)^n dx\ge 0$.
Then let $0<t<\pi/2$ be small and write

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)^n dx = \int_0^{\pi/2-t} \sin(x)^n dx + \int_{\pi/2-t}^{\pi/2} \sin(x)^n dx \le \frac\pi{2} \sin(\pi/2-t)^n + t$$

Now take $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$ on both sides to see that

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)^n dx \le t$$

Since this holds for all $t>0$ we have

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)^n dx=0$$

Thus the limit exists and equals $0$.

Comment: How does one do the second question which i have asked.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see that one. It is a bit more subtle. Notice that $\int_0^{2\pi n} |\sin(x)|^n dx = 4n \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)^n dx$. One can show that this diverges. Actually one can compute the value by comparing to the Gamma function as $4n \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma((n+1)/2)}{2\Gamma(n/2+1)}$, now use Stirling's formula to see this tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. The same idea should work for the first question as well :) For you aply the gamma function formula denominator would increase much faster than the numerator and hence the integral would converge to ZERO

Comment: The sequence $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)^n dx$ is decreasing and bounded, therefore convergent so there is no need to use lim sup

Comment: Good point! @EugenCovaci

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the definition of limits. Given an $\epsilon>0$, find an $n$ (not necessarily the *first* $n$, that's irrelevant) such that $\int_0^{2\pi}|\sin x|^ndx<\epsilon$.

Now, assuming $\epsilon$ is small enough, let $x_1, x_2$ be so that $$0<x_1<\frac\pi2<x_1+\frac\epsilon4<x_2<\frac{3\pi}2<x_2+\frac\epsilon4<2\pi$$
and let $n$ be large enough that on $[0,x_1]\cap[x_1+\epsilon/4, x_2]\cap[x_2+\frac\epsilon4]$, we have $\sup |\sin x|^n < \frac{\epsilon}{4\pi}$. This makes $\int_0^{2\pi}|\sin x|^ndx < \epsilon$.

Comment: A downvote without explanation doesn't really help me to improve this answer. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I wasn't that one who downvoted you, but I don't think this hint is particularly useful because I'm quite sure the OP had some thoughts about using the limit's definition.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Might be, might not be. The only thing we can tell from the question itself is that the OP tried squeezing it between $0$ and $x$, which didn't work. Had he added a comment saying he already tried this, I would expand my answer to help. This is why it matters that they provide their own thoughts and attempts.

Comment: Anyway, the downvoting was not necessary, +1 to cancel it

Comment: -1.  This answer could be given for *any* question asking to show a limit is $0$.  It doesn't address the specifics of this question, so it is not helpful.

Comment: @Strants I am happy you at least commented. Makes it easier to address it. In my opinion this _is_ helpful. Not every limit is easily decidable from the definition. Some are easier to decide using various theorems like the squeeze theorem. It seems to me that the OP has forgotten that some times it is actually best to forgo all the advanced results and go back to basics. Had the question or comments mentioned that he had actually tried to use the definition directly, I would've been more detailed in my answer. As it stands, this is a hint of the "This is the way you want to do it"-variety.

Comment: @EugenCovaci "Cancellation" votes are a distortion of the voting mechanism. Boasting about them is an indication that you do not care one iota about how the site is supposed to function. (On top of this general remark, the irony in the case at hand is that you yourself declared that you "don't think this hint is particularly useful", which is one of the canonical grounds for downvote. Logic, please?)

Comment: @Arthur And that you for replying!  Looking back, my comment may not have been as constructive as it could have been, so I'll rephrase.  

The central difficulty in this problem (as I see it) is that while $|\sin(x)|^n$ goes to zero almost everywhere as $n \to \infty$, it does not do so uniformly in $x$.  As a result, any solution needs to have some form of the following argument(s): (1) that this non-uniform convergence is enough, or (2) that we have uniform convergence to $0$ except on sets which can be as small as we please (where $|\sin x|^n$ is bounded). . .

Comment: . . . All the 'interesting' parts of the proof go into proving/citing one of these two assertions (IMO).  You may be right that the OP was looking for some high-powered theorem, and couldn't see the forest for the trees.  If that was the case, I agree your remark was helpful, and could have made a good comment, but I still don't think it's sufficient as an answer.  If you could add a brief sketch of how you address (2) (or (1)), though, I'd happily reverse my downvote.

Comment: @Strants Well, OK, then. I'll stop being stubborn.

Comment: @Arthur Never an easy thing to do!  You have my upvote. :)

Answer (score 1):

As for $\int_{0}^{2n\pi} |\sin(x)|^{n} \ dx,$ note this is the same as $n\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\sin(x)|^{n} \ dx= n \int_{0}^{2\pi} |\cos(x)|^{n} \ dx.$

Now for $x \ge 0, \cos x \ge 1-x^2.$ So

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} |\cos(x)|^{n} \ dx > \int_{0}^{1/\sqrt n} \cos^n(x)\ dx \ge \int_{0}^{1/\sqrt n} (1-x^2)^n \ dx \ge (1/\sqrt n) (1-1/n)^n \sim 1/(e\sqrt n).$$

Therefore $\int_{0}^{2n\pi} |\sin(x)|^{n} \ dx$ is bounded below by an expression asymptotic to $\sqrt n/e.$ Hence the limit in question is $\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

We'll show that the integral over $[0, \pi]$ converges to zero, which is equivalent to the desired result. Let $I = [0, \frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon] \cup [\frac{\pi}{2} + \epsilon, \pi]$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ sufficiently small. It is easy to verify that $|sin(x)|$ attains a maximum that is less than one on $I$. Since $f(t, n) = t^n$ ($t$, $n >0$) is an increasing function of $t$ and goes to zero as $n \to \infty$ for $t < 1$, this implies that convergence of $sin(x)^n$ to zero as $n \to \infty$ is uniform on $I$. Therefore the portion of the integral taken over $I$ vanishes. For all $n$ the integrand is bounded above by one on $[0, \pi] - I$. Therefore as $\epsilon \to 0$ and $n \to \infty$, the portion of the integral taken over $[0, \pi] - I$ also vanishes. It follows that the integral over $[0, \pi]$ converges to 0 as $n \to \infty$, as claimed.